# Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)

Tags: salesforce, httprequest, httpresponse, apex-code, shopify

I must make a http request to Shopify in Salesforce. I used following url format as endpoint url for setEndpoint method.

```
HttpRequest req= new HttpRequest(); 
req.setEndpoint('https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.xml'); 
req.setMethod('GET');
```

I get following log:

```
CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[18]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]
```

And I get return value from body of HttpResponse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <hash> <errors>[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)</errors> </hash>
```

Also I have tried to following structure but I haven't been succesful.

```
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(apikey+ ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
```

What should I do for HttpResponse status code be 200.

Comment: Are you able to use the https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.xml in your browser? If not you probably need to (re)generate a new apikey:password.

Comment: Yes I have tried. It has worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

"Basic" word is case-sensitive. I changed "BASIC" with it. The problem is fixed.

```
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('apikey:password');
    String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
```